# [Java-Opencv]: How convert an image from Cartesian space to Polar space?

Tags: java, image, opencv, processing

Hi guys I have to convert this image:

[image]

in this:

[image]

in Java.

This is my code:

```
     double Cx =original_img.width()/2;
     double Cy =original_img.height()/2;
     int rho,theta;

     for (int i=0;i<img.getHeight();i++){
         for(int j=0;j<img.getWidth();j++){


             rho = (int)(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(i-Cx,2) + Math.pow(j-Cy,2)));  
             theta = (int)(Math.atan2((j-Cy),(i-Cx)));

             int color; 

             try{

                color = img.getRGB((int)rho, (int)theta);
             }catch(Exception e){
                color = 0;
             }

             int  alpha = (color>>24) & 0xff;
             int  red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
             int  green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
             int  blue = color & 0x000000ff;
             int pixel = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
             img2.setRGB(rho, theta, pixel);


             System.out.println("point: "+rho+" "+theta);
         }
     }
```

What's wrong? 
I haven't found a simple and good Log-Polar transform in java.

My steps are:

1) take an original image (original_img)

2) cycling on the rows and cols of image

3) calculate rho and theta (are the new X and Y coordinates for the new pixel, right?)

4) get color pixel at coords (rho,theta)

5) create new pixel and set at the new coords.

What miss or wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: is that javacv or opencv's java api ?

Comment: How are Cartesian coords apply to an image? Through the dimensions of the image? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Cartesian and polar are 2D, images are normally considered multi-dimensional, so what?

Comment: i'm trying to archieve this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33648/Polar-View-of-an-Image

Comment: what do you mean by "how are the Cartesian coords apply to an image"?
i have used:  
Mat original_img  = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());

for read an image by a file

Comment: btw, [Core.cartToPolar](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#cartToPolar(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))

Comment: how can i use cartToPolar? can you give me my code change with it?

Answer (score 1):

Now I get it. You want to apply to pixel coordinates. Sorry.

```
 rho = (int)(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(i-Cx,2) + Math.pow(j-Cy,2)));  
 theta = (int)(Math.atan2((j-Cy),(i-Cx)));
```

Why would you want `int` instead of `double` on the above code? If not required I would suggest use `double`. Also the code is wrong, you are subtracting the dimension each time. Do not do this:

```
 rho = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(i,2) + Math.pow(j,2));  
 theta = Math.atan2((j),(i));
```

That looks fine to me. But why you want to convert to polar anyway?

P.S. The above code has noting to do with Opencv of course.

Edit: If I am interpreting correctly the algorithm you the Cartesian coordinates should be in the center of the image so use your code:

I cannot tell you about the rotation part though but from your statement `get color pixel at coords (rho,theta)` I am guessing that you don't have to rotate the image. The effect does not require this.

Comment: Hi!! thank you for the reply, i need to convert an image for an exam at my university. I'm following the instruction of a paper for an project :(

I used int instead of double because the method .setRGB (int, int, int) requires 3 int.
But the method I used is correct? the image needs a rotation and a translation after that?

Comment: in the paper there is a formula for rho and theta. where rho denotes radial distance from the center (Cx,Cy) and theta denotes angle. that's why i have used this formula.

Comment: My mistake, I haven't noticed that in beginning of your code. It is correct I think. I will correct my code.